# Wack-A-Mole for school - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The command `destroymole()` is unable to run without `mole = tk.Button(root, ...)`,
but `mole` can't run without `destroymole()`
How can I get them to be defined for the other one at the same time?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075,rely=0.075,relheight=0.85,relwidth=0.85,)


def destroymole():
    mole.destroy()

mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE",relief="raised", command=destroymole(), 
x=random.randint(300,700),y=random.randint(300, 700), height=20, width=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [formatting instructions](/help/formatting) for help on formatting your questions and answers using SO's markdown syntax. Also remember to check the indentation of your python code, because badly indented python code is invalid python code.

Comment: `command=destroymole()` should be `command=destroymole` instead.  Also should the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` options be put in a separate `mole.place()`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `mole` in the line `mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE",relief="raised", command=destroymole(),  x=random.randint(300,700),y=random.randint(300, 700), height=20, width=30)`, In that same line, you *call* the `destroymole()` function and pass its return value as the `command` argument, but `mole` isn't defined yet so calling `destroymole()` gives you an error.

What you *actually meant to do* was pass the *function*  `destroymole` as the `command` argument so that the button would know which function to call when it is clicked. Change `command=destroymole()` in that line to `command=destroymole` and the error will be gone.