# Can I create random x and y coordinates for a button - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, python-3.9

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random

root = tk.Tk() 

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.85,)

def destroymole():
    mole.destroy()

mole = tk.Button(root,text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=destroymole, x=random.randint(300,700), y=random.randint(300, 700), height=20, width=30)

root.mainloop()
```

After running this I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\GUI APP.py", line 15, in
<module>
    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE",relief="raised", command=destroymole, x=random.randint(300,700),y=random.randint(300,
700), height=20, width=30)   File
"C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 2647, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-x"
```

However, the main one is the last line and I'm pretty sure it is to do with the random number

If there are any other apparent issues then please tell me because this is all a mystery to me.

Comment: Did you read my comment in your another question [wack-a-mole-for-school-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903945/wack-a-mole-for-school-python)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know there were comments lol. But thank you, I now know to check comments. (And how to fix my code)

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory: the Button class doesn't support `x` and `y` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not placed the button. Hope, you know that there are three ways by which you can set up the widget in the window (place, pack, grid). I have used the place method and passed the random value in the parameter.

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random

root = tk.Tk() 

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.85,)

def destroymole():
    mole.destroy()

mole = tk.Button(root,text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=destroymole)
mole.place(x=random.randint(300,700), y=random.randint(300, 700), height=20, width=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Rest for any query feel free to ask me.